How to get attribute of a foreign key inside serializer in Django REST framework?
I have two models named Market, Exchange
class Exchange(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class Market(models.Model):
    exchange = models.ForeignKey(Exchange, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.FloatField(default=0.0)

What I need to do is get name field in Exchange Model inside MarketSerializer ->
class MarketSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Market
        fields = ('exchange_name', 'price', )

How can I do that?

You can archive those things using SerializerMethodField() like this
class MarketSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    exchange_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Market
        fields = ('exchange_name', 'price', )

    def get_exchange_name(self, obj):
        return obj.exchange.name 

